# Manage devices from code (C#)

Tags: c#, bluetooth, device, wiimote, wii

I am currently writing/experimenting with a wiimote touchscreen application in C# and one of the main issues is that after I connect my wiimote via Bluetooth, it cannot connect back again until the device is removed and then re-installed. This makes for a along tedious process just to set up the wiimote for use with the application. Is there anything that can automatically remove devices, then add and install the devices drivers? The wiimote always has to reinstall the driver afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did a project on the Wiimote, faced the exact same problem you're having.

I found a program named [WiimoteConnect](http://www.wiimoteproject.com/bluetooth-and-connectivity-knowledge-center/wiimoteconnect-0-6-%28support-for-autoconnect%29/):

This little program automatically handles all the install/uninstall bluetooth connection stuff for you.

Comment: The download isn't available anymore :(

Comment: I have it downloaded, since it is free software I could share/email it to you :)

Comment: Okay, my email is kiroyakuza@ymail.com. Thanks